# NuKeeper with Azure Pipelines and Bitbucket Server throws an error on pull request creation

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, nuget, updates, bitbucket-server

in TFS (Azure Pipelines) I have a task to run nukeeper repo command:
`nukeeper repo "https://bitbucket.xxx.com/scm/myproject/myrepo.git" <token> --api "https://bitbucket.xxx.com/scm/myproject/myrepo.git" --consolidate --source https://tfs/tfs/XXX/_packaging/main/nuget/v3/index.json --verbosity detailed`

The command starts succesfully, repo is cloned, updates detected, a new branch created changes committed and pushed, BUT it seems only locally.

When NuKeeper tries to create a new pull request, an exception is thrown.

In logs:

`OpenPullRequest: Error NotFound 2021-03-22T16:41:31.1464196Z Response NotFound is not success, body: 2021-03-22T16:41:31.1465586Z Updates failed NuKeeperException : OpenPullRequest: Error NotFound 2021-03-22T16:41:31.1466638Z {"errors":[{"context":null,"message":"Repository \"xxx\" of project with key \"xxx\" has no branch \"nukeeper-update-3-packages-9F8F13D133529FB443D130FFB8330A78\"","exceptionName":"com.atlassian.bitbucket.commit.NoSuchCommitException"}]}`

Locally there is a temp folder with name corresponding cloned repo and branch

Answer (score 0):

1. If you use TFS (on-premises Azure DevOps Server), you could login the build agent machine, and run the commands locally, to see whether you would reproduce the issue.
2. The error indicated `"Repository \"xxx\" of project with key \"xxx\" has no branch \"nukeeper-update-3-packages-9F8F13D133529FB443D130FFB8330A78\"`, you could check whether the branch exists on the server.